# How to track differences on each rows in sql

Tags: sql, while-loop, case-when

I have this audit table and want to add a hardcoded status report on my view. Record number is dynamic depending on how many changes has been made. I'm thinking if this is possible in case switch to manipulate data? Or do I need to use a loop?

```
DBAction    DateFrom    Dateto  Status
Update  12/15/2020  12/25/2021  Date To has been updated
Update  12/15/2020  12/15/2021  Date From has been updated
Insert  12/13/2020  12/15/2021  New
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you create a db fiddle with a sample of data from your audit table?

Comment: Hi Gerard, can you provide me a hint or share a logic on how can I achieve this?

Comment: A link, perhaps?  https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tgR5p3nW1GBnCDW6PGzJJp/0

Comment: Hi Again, I found one useful sql function which is LAG/LEAD. This function will cater my requirements. Thank you and have a great day ahead.

Comment: I had a look, I thought that was the result you wanted to obtain.  Not the original data.

Comment: How is only "date to" changed in the first row?  Is `insert` always associated with "new"?  What is the ordering of the rows?  The logic is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lag/Lead sql function will cater the work.